# Asp.Net MVC 3/4 save and create buttons

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic CRUD application in ASP.Net MVC 4. The Create view of the CRUD format has a form with "save" and "cancel" buttons.  When I click on save button, the data are stored correctly in the database and the view refresh to the previous list records.
I want to make a "save and add" button where the user click on it and then the data will stored and load again the "create" view.
Sorry my bad english...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mfanto's point, if you wanted to be able to detect, as I believe you do, which button was clicked, just create both buttons with type="submit" and both with the same name.  However, give them both different values. Like:

```
<input type="submit" name="whichButton" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="whichButton" value="SaveAndAdd" />
```

Then in your controller, you'll receive the button value in a parameter named the same as the button:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(Model model,string whichButton){
    switch(whichButton) {
        case "Save" : //do stuff and redirect to the list of records
        break;
        case "SaveAndAdd" : //do stuff and redirect to create
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the redirection in your Create action. This is called the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. When you POST your form data, your action will save it to the database, and then redirect somewhere else. Right now it's redirecting you to your list of items action (maybe RedirectToAction("Index")). Change it to redirect back to Create.

```
public ActionResult Create(DataModel data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // save data here

        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
}
```